# How can I debug a custom debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging

I wrote a custom debugger as described in [perldebguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts.html#Writing-Your-Own-Debugger). There's something wrong with my debugger code, though, so I want to step through my `DB::DB()` and `DB::sub()` routines line-by-line to isolate the problem.

I suppose I can do this by setting [`$^D`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5ED) to `1<<30`, since the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts.html#Debugger-Internals) says:

> When the execution of your program reaches a point that can hold a breakpoint, the `DB::DB()` subroutine is called if any of the variables `$DB::trace`, `$DB::single`, or `$DB::signal` is true. These variables are not localizable. This feature is disabled when executing inside `DB::DB()`, including functions called from it **unless `$^D & (1<<30)` is true.**
>
> When execution of the program reaches a subroutine call, a call to `&DB::sub (args)` is made instead, with `$DB::sub` holding the name of the called subroutine. (This doesn't happen if the subroutine was compiled in the DB package.)

*(emphasis added)*

People on the IRC #perl-help channel said that with `$^D & (1<<30)` I may be able to debug my debugger but they didn't know any details beyond that.

How can I trace the execution of my `DB::DB()` and `DB::sub()` subroutines step-by-step?

**UPD**
According to the answer below. When set `$^D |= (1<<30)` flag this allows me to debug debugger commands which is defined outside of `DB` namespace, but that is not an answer  for question: *How to disable that feature when executing inside DB::DB?*

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Without knowing more details about what you're trying to do, there doesn't seem to be an actual question here.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "debug the debugger"? Are you trying to debug a custom debugger you've written? Can you give a specific example?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Yes, I am trying to debug a custome debugger.

Comment: I'm not sure setting `$^D` to `1<<30` even works properly. For one thing, printing it resets the value to 0 because it doesn't match the [standard debug flags](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-D*_letters_): `perl -MDevel::Peek -e'$^D |= (1<<30); Dump $^D; print "$^D\n"; Dump $^D'`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: am confusing also because of that.

Comment: I edited your question pretty heavily to make it clear what you're asking, I hope you don't mind. You can call subroutines from inside `DB::DB`, which means you can call `DB::DB` recursively, but I'm not sure how useful that is. More useful would be a way to temporarily restore the default debugger (`perl5db.pl`). Maybe you could alias `DB::DB` to the version in `perl5db.pl`? Also, have you tried asking on [perl5-porters](http://lists.perl.org/list/perl5-porters.html)? If anyone knows, it would be them.

Comment: #p5p says that is not possible to trace any DB::* subs. but I invented a trick how to complete that. I think I may answer the question myself in a month after complete that feature in my custom debugger

Answer (score 1):

This is my custom debugger [Devel::DebugHooks](https://github.com/KES777/Devel-DebugHooks/tree/develop) which I want to debug.

When I run this expression from debugger `$^D|=(1<<30)` and after that run debugger command, like `vars 2 $x`, this will allow me to debug code which is called from DB:: namespace.

> This feature is disabled when executing inside DB::DB(), including functions called from it unless `$^D & (1<<30)` is true

This sentence from DOC just makes confusion.
The feature is **NOT** disabled when executing inside `DB::DB()` unless `$^D & (1<<30)` is true.
**This feature is disabled only for functions called from `DB::DB()` when `$^D & (1<<30)` is true**

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13327349)

Comment: It is not complete answer so I do not accept it. I am working on my custom debugger now. After I complete it I will complete this answer too.